# Global Historic GIS Data

Tags: geospatial, historical, geocoding, climate

This is a basic question concerning data availability. I am looking for global historic geo-spatial data covering the past 2,000 or 3,000 years. Variables of interest are biomes, temperature, precipitation, soil characteristics, mineral deposits, rivers etc. The data should come as multiple cross-sections rather than 3,000 year averages. Frequencies of not more than a few hundred years would be great.

As you are all well aware, geography is not constant over time. Human activity and a changing climate alter biomes, rivers dry up and are re-directed, mineral deposits are used an eventually exhausted, temperature and precipitation follow global and regional trends.

Paleoclimatology is an interesting field modeling long-term changes. Geo-spatial data on temperature and precipitation of the past few million years is freely available online. That is great, but this data is with its estimates usually averaged over a few thousand years not what I am looking for. I need a shorter time horizon with a higher frequency, as outlined in the first paragraph. Something like [HYDE](https://themasites.pbl.nl/tridion/en/themasites/hyde/) data for other variables.

There are estimates for small regions or individual countries for different points in history. That does not help as I need a global scale. Merging these smaller puzzle pieces together to create a global picture is often difficult as definitions, assumptions and map quality vary widely.

Projects like [DARMC](https://darmc.harvard.edu/), [AfricaMap](https://worldmap.harvard.edu/africamap/), [HYDE](https://themasites.pbl.nl/tridion/en/themasites/hyde/), [PaleoClim](http://paleoclim.org/) and [WorldClim](https://www.worldclim.org/paleo-climate1) have done a great job in putting together geo-spatial data in easily accessible formats at the larger geographic scale for different points in human history. However, there is still a lot missing.

**I'm looking for any data sources that meet the following requirements:**

- *Format:* Any geo-coded/geospatial format. It can be points, lines, polygons or raster grids.
- *Spatial Extent*: cover approximately the entire planet (or at least major regions)
- *Time Frame*: covering the past 2,000 or 3,000 years in multiple cross-sections rather than 3,000 year averages. Frequencies of not more than a few hundred years would be great.
- *Topic*: related to any of these or similar paleoclimate variables:

  - Biomes
  - Temperature
  - Precipitation
  - Soil characteristics
  - Mineral deposits
  - Rivers

I am looking forward to your suggestions. Any comments are welcome.